# Python, Class has no Attribute. How can I return a value of a value that has been passed into class?

Tags: python, class

Newbie..

code:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, emailAddress, fName):
        parts = emailAddress.split('@')
        if len(parts) != 2:
            raise Exception("Invalid email address: %s" % emailAddress)

        self.emailAddress = emailAddress
        self.emailMd5     = hashlib.md5(emailAddress).hexdigest()
        self.domain       = parts[1]
        self.fName        = fName
```

I want to be able to access 'fName', and return the value thats stored in it.  Obviously this is not the way to do it!  Working with example API code, and trying to extend it.  I pass into user(emailAddress, fName) (First Name).

There code later goes on to use:

```
emailData['recipient'] = users[emailData['recipientMd5']].emailAddress
```

Which works, so I figured what I would do would also?

I know this should be a simple fix.  Not sure what to google though, and example class tutorials I've read haven't covered what I'm trying to do.

Comment: can you show where you're calling fName and it's not working, and also post the error message you are getting?

Comment: calling from "main()" class: u = User(emailAddress,fName), and trying to get value in another class.  It was showing up "blank", so tried logging value to a file in the main() class.  The error is: AttributeError: User has no attribute 'fname'

Comment: okay, well, it would be good for you to copy/paste this stuff into your question, rather than just alluding to it in the comments here.  This still isn't showing where you are trying to do u.fName, which would be useful to see.  Also, for the error you've described, User shouldn't have an attribute 'fname', but it should have an attribute 'fName'.  Did you forget to capitalize the 'N'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import hashlib
class User:
    def __init__(self, emailAddress, fName):
        parts = emailAddress.split('@')
        if len(parts) != 2:
            raise Exception("Invalid email address: %s" % emailAddress)
        self.emailAddress = emailAddress
        self.emailMd5     = hashlib.md5(emailAddress).hexdigest()
        self.domain       = parts[1]
        self.fName        = fName

u = User("me@you.com","uname") # create instance
print u.fName # print instance attribute
```

You can access attributes directly from each instance.

Comment: AHH I get what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to do User.fName, when I should be doing u.fName

Comment: Yes, you instantiate the instance passing in any required parameters then you can access any attributes or methods of the class using the instance name like above.